# Conversion of "to look cool"

Tags: grammaire, usage, france, francais-classique

When google translator is used, The sentences converted to french are not properly converted.
can some one tell whats the conversion of the line in french:

"Trying to look cool in foreign language"

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on the context the line should be used into ?

Comment: I  just want the conversion of this specific line to french. For convenience you can say , I am saying a line : I am trying to look cool by using french language

Comment: *J'essaye d'avoir l'air cool en parlant (or écrivant en) français*

Comment: I agree with jiliagre - don't be surprised if "cool" is translated as "cool" in French, that is indeed an English word very frequently used in French, with more or less the same meaning of "fashionable".

Comment: Since the English isn't a typical wording it's not surprising that GT would give an even worse translation than usual. But I think jlliagre captures the probable meaning

Comment: Bottom line: don't use Google translator !

Comment: @Greg I'd rather say, you can use google translator but don't blindingly trust it. Take it with a grain of salt! By the way, GT is not that bad with the updated sentence: " I am trying to look cool by using french language" gives *J'essaie d'avoir l'air cool en utilisant la langue française*

Answer (score 1):

**Trying to look** can be translated as

> Essayer d'avoir l'air.

But for the second part, it depends of the context: "in foreign language", does that mean you're doing as if you could talk it, pretending to be fluent, or you want to express the language you're using?

If it's the latter, it would be something like:

> J'essaye d'avoir cool en parlant Anglais.

Note that "cool" can have many different translations, depending of the "politeness" you want: it could be translated like classy:

> J'essaye d'avoir l'air classe en parlant Anglais